# Angular 1.x duplicate identifier on TFS build

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tfs, tfsbuild, typescript-typings

I have an Angular 1.4 application written using Typescript, making use of various typings e.g. angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-block-ui.
This application builds on my local machine.

However, when using a TFS build controller I receive numerous errors with messages along the lines of "Duplciate identifier 'angular'".

Now obviously each typings file will declare a namespace e.g. "angular.sanitize". The error will occur if the angular namespace has already been declared in another typings file.

I do not really understand why the errors do not occur on my development machine but do on the build server. I am using TFS 2010 for source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out.

The build server had a different version of Typescript installed. Once I made this the same as my development machine all issues went away and my build worked.